# Get multiple data from tables Using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

```
public ActionResult Hotel_Read(string text)
{
    var result = GetHotel().Where(c => c.Name.Contains(text) || c.City.Contains(text) || c.Country.Contains(text)).ToList();
    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

private static IEnumerable<HotelViewModel> GetHotel()
{
    using (TravelAgancyEntities1 db = new TravelAgancyEntities1())
    {
        var query = db.Hotels
                      .Include(p => p.City.Country).Distinct().ToList();

        return query.Select(Hotel => new HotelViewModel
         {
             Name = Hotel.Name,
             City = Hotel.City.City_Name,
    **Line 10-** Country = Hotel.City.Country.Country_Name,//!!!

         });
    }
}
```

When I run the code without line 10, it is working successfully, but when that code is run *with* line 10, then it's not working.

[image]

Comment: You know we can't see the line numbers and we're loathe to count them ourselves? Also, what's the error?

Comment: you cant do this as you are doing. qury has object with hotels only.

Comment: what you actually want in your code and in result please be brief your question.

Comment: Hotel.City.Country. is collection of countries. you need to iterate on it to get single instance.

Comment: Include(p => p.City.Select(x => x.Country)).Distinct().ToList();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your code should run properly. the only thing that makes me suspicious, is that you are trying to retrieve all Hotel table data plus 2 other table(with **include**)
try this :

```
var q = (from x in db.Hotels.Include(c => c.City).Include(c =>  c.City.Country)
                         where x.Id == 5030
                         select x).Distinct().ToList();
string s = q[0].City.Country.Country_Name;
```

Limit your select with **Where** clause.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Includes here because there is no application logic involved in creation of `HotelViewModel` instances.

Simple query:

```
db.Hotels.Select(h => new HotelViewModel
         {
             Name = h.Name,
             City = h.City.City_Name,
             Country = h.City.Country.Country_Name,
         }).ToList();
```

Will return from the DB exactly the data that you need.

When you first do Includes, and then call ToList();:

```
var query = db.Hotels.Include(p => p.City.Select(x => x.Country))
                     .Distinct()
                     .ToList();
```

You fetch form DB all the Hotel properties, all the City properties and 
all the Country properties while all you really need is only their names.